# How do get the URL of a Not Found page, in order to display it in a custom 404 page?

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

Ok, I have a issue with my Webserver, when I try using

```
<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" ?>
```

It turns up the file it's self:
Eg. blah.com/404.php

Also how would I do this with a 403 page?
I know its possible and I've tried

```
    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

but noting turns up, or sometimes it's just a zero.
This is my first time with a 404, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, are you *redirecting* to the 404/403 page? Are you loading it directly in the browser?

Comment: The status-code pages are handled by the webserver, not by PHP

Comment: You have an issue, we know that. But what you are going to do?! We cant guess! Give us more info.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is always empty when accessing the url directly in your browser.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I'm using bad links to test the pages, but the URI isn't being shown, its either missing or '0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Issue, You must post a relative path, not a direct link, otherwise it will redirect to that page instead of showing the 404.

Eg:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

That way the .htacess doesn't redirect to Yoursite.com/notfound.php
It will also send a 404 (Not Found) instead of a 200 (OK)

Answer (score 0):

A 404 status code should be returned by the url which is "not found". So instead of redirecting to another php file you should 'return' this code instantly.

You should have a look at error document handling in `.htaccess` files. Something like this may help you:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
```

This will return a 404 status code. The good thing for this solution: you can access `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in your notfound.php file and use it to display an error message or any other action.

Comment: Did you access your page directly or did you use another link to get there?

Comment: I used another typed in random letters and it redirected me to 404.php  but it didn't say what the url I typed in was, nor does it if its a link from html.

Comment: Are you sure this is a redirect when using `ErrorDocument ...`? When I type in a random url, it only returns the contents of my 404.php. The url is still the same and so `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the current (not found) url.